# Spring Cloud Data Flow Passing Parameters to Data Flow Server

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

What is the format for passing in additional arguments or environment variables to the Data Flow Server in SCDF running on Kubernetes? When running locally in Docker Compose, I can do something like below, but not sure what the equivalent is when deploying to Kubernetes using the helm chart.

```
dataflow-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:-2.9.0-SNAPSHOT}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    ports:
      - "9393:9393"
    environment:
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=pkc...:9092
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
      - ...
```

I see that there's a parameter for the helm chart, server.extraEnvVars, but i'm just not exactly sure how to set the above **spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties** parameters into a format where it will be picked up by the Data Flow Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties you are looking for might be [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/) under
Kafka Chart Parameters
->   externalKafka.brokers

So in your case I would try

```
helm install my-release --set externalKafka.borkers=pkc...:9092 bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow
```

But I don't see a parameter for the ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm property.

You could try running in the SCDF shell with something like

```
stream deploy yourstream --properties "spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https..., spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=pkc...:9092"
```

Comment: Yeah, setting externalKafka.brokers works, but doesn't work when trying to connect to Confluent Cloud. I think you can probably also use a ConfigMap and Secrets to get it to work by passing those parameters to helm. And passing the parameters to the individual streams does work as well. Thanks for the alternative suggestions!